# Firestore document not created with await

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to add a document in Firestore but my code isnt working as intended.

```
private val todoCollection = db.collection(TODOS)
private val userCollection = db.collection(USERS)
 
suspend fun insertTodo(todoName: String) {
        withContext(defaultDispatcher) {   //defaultDispatchers is Dispatchers.IO
            val userId = auth.currentUser!!.uid
            val todoId = todoCollection.document().id
 
            //This works
            userCollection.document(userId).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    val currentUser = document.toObject<User>()
                    val todo = Todo(todoId, todoName, currentUser!!)
                    todoCollection.document(todoId).set(todo)
                }
            }

            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d("todoerror", "$e")
            }
 
            //This doesnt work
            try {
            val currentUser = userCollection.document(userId).get().await().toObject<User>()
            val todo = Todo(todoId, todoName, currentUser!!)
            todoCollection.document(todoId).set(todo).await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("todoerror", "$e")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried logging the exceptions, but no exception occurred

Comment: Please show us how you handled the exceptions.

Comment: I got the solution, the viewmodel of the fragment from where I was adding the "todo" was scoped to fragment, so whenever I added the "todo" , the fragment is destroyed and I was navigated to my HomeFragment and the Job was cancelled

Comment: @Ansh T Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

My app adds a todo by launching a seperate fragment which has the viewmodel scoped to the fragment.

```
private val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels()
```

So when I add todo, it navigates back to the fragment of todos and this fragment gets destroyed. As a result, 'insertTodo' function gives "Job was cancelled" exception. To prevent this modify the above snippet to:

```
private val viewModel: ViewModel by activityViewModels()
```